# The connection was reset when creating a new node

Tags: debugging

On a localhost environment, when I try to create a new node, I get this message:

> *The connection was reset*.

There is some issue with css, cache and/or registry since when I disable the css aggregation it works for the next node and it stops for the next node creating. In order to work again for a new node it needs enabling the Css aggregation and so on.

Also when I clear caches I get this kind of messages:

> *The following module has moved within the file system: views_test. In order to fix this, clear caches or put the module back in its original location. For more [warning] information, see the documentation page. bootstrap.inc:1128*

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact two issues in your question.

To solve *The connection was reset* issue, have you tried to run [rebuild_registry](http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) ?

```
drush dl registry_rebuild-7.x
drush en registry_rebuild-7.x -y
drush cc drush
drush rr
```

Some people also reported that with Coder Module but not only, they had to edit `httpd.conf`, increasing the Apache stack size to 8MB

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

For the 2nd issue *The following module has moved within the file system*, this appeared since Drupal 7.50 release. A straight way to correct these errors is to use [Module Missing Message Fixer](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer). You'll find alternatives and full explanations [in this DO post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215).

Comment: Hi,I have both tried registry rebuild and increasing apache stack size but nothing worked. There is no httpd.conf file on apache so I created one but still it didn't work .Doh

Comment: I used the module "Module Missing Message Fixer" but it says "No Missing Modules Found!!! "   I have seen also other people have the same issue

Comment: Check the DO post, I had some of same issues and solved them either by creating a fake module (.info and .module) at the searched place, then `en/dis/uninstall` them...

Comment: Thanks for the help,I only am concerned about the Connection reset issue.THe other issue I just cleared the cache and it worked.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 16.04 and apache server 2.4.18 . I read that newer apache server do not have an httpd.conf file that's why I guess I have none.

Comment: Correct, you conf files should be then into `/etc/apache2/conf-available` dir. I guess you did put yours there or checked if there was any for your current project. Post smthing whenever you got it solved. Good luck :)

Comment: There was nothing there,so I created such a file but still no luck.Thanks anyway for the help.Cheers